# Node.js readline module: stop reprinting the line just read

Tags: node.js, stdin

I'm using the `readline` module in Node (12) to accept user input as such:

```js
import * as readline from "readline";

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
console.log("input is a TTY?",process.stdin.isTTY);

const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout, prompt: '> '});
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line' ,inputLine => { inputStringLines.push(inputLine); rl.prompt(); });
rl.on('close',() => { console.log('input has closed'); main(); });
```

The lines are correctly captured into my `inputStringLines` array but annoyingly, the process is printing out every line just read:

[image]

How can I get rid of the extra lines (the ones without the `>` prompt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by changing how run my script.  Before, I used `nodemon` with node's `-r ts-node/register` option.  The issue went away when I switched to using [`ts-node-dev`](https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev) to execute the script.

Note also that `process.stdin.isTTY` is now correctly set whereas it was undefined before (look at the first line in the image below, vs in the original post)

[image]

Still don't know the root cause, but I'm happy to move on.